# Create checklist monthly and quarterly in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created checklist as per the attached image in excel.[image: Checklist image]

Explanation- I have to create checklist to check the progress of reports in excel. I have divided the period as monthly and quarterly.

**Note** : Quarterly includes March, June, September, December and Monthly includes remaining months.

B4 cell is checked quarterly, where as B5 and B6 cells are checked Monthly basis.
The checkbox's on column C is liked to column D.
Cell A1 is drop-down menu which has months from JAN - DEC.

I want to select March in Cell A1 (that is quarterly period), after selecting the quarter month- In cell E5 & E6 I want to display N/A in Monthly and in F5 & F6 i need to show 1 or 0 as per the checkbox in column C.

Like wise if i select APRIL( Which is not quarter month) I need to display "N/A" in F5 & F6 and 1 or 0 in E4 based on checkbox checked value true or false.

Can some one suggest logic.

Comment: *'Can some one suggest logic.'* is not a **specific** programming question. [idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *Checklist Logic* Checklist:

☑ Design Template.

☐ Learn how to use Excel's **`IF`** Worksheet Function. *(see below)*

☐ Use **`IF`** Function to change value of cells `E5:F6` depending on value of drop-down.

---

### More information:

- Office.com : **[IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)** (worksheet function)
- Office.com : **[Logical functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/logical-functions-reference-e093c192-278b-43f6-8c3a-b6ce299931f5)** (Excel reference)